# How I can select from two different table but order with time

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

I have two different tables that named "groupposts" and "posts"
In these tables there are these column
I mean name of "time" column are different in both !
I need to use **UNION** for selecting these tables

Table GROUPPOSTS

```
    ID      Gpost      Gtime
    ________________________
    1       Test       3
```

Table POSTS

```
    ID      Ppost      Ptime
    ________________________
    1       Test       1
```

I want select from both but order by Gtime and PTime desc 
Tell me how I can get it and how I can show them
I mean how I can show "ppost" If "ptime" will select sooner or what about "gpost" if it will be ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you selecting from them without the ordering?

Comment: dear @Anthony Grist , I want order them by time column , but time column's name is different in those tables

Comment: That's not remotely what I asked you. I know what you want to do, I'm asking you to post the SQL query you already have to select from your two tables **without worrying about the order**. Is it a join? Is it a union?

Comment: I need to use Union for two different tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
(SELECT Gpost AS post, Gtime AS time FROM GROUPPOSTS)
UNION
(SELECT Ppost AS post, Ptime AS time FROM POSTS)
ORDER BY time
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this?

```
select *
from
(
  select id, gpost, gtime as xtime from GROUPPOSTS
  union all
  select id, ppost, ptime as xtime from POSTS
)
order by xtime;
```

EDIT: Oops, above statement is much too complicated for what has been asked. The ORDER BY clause works on the complete query and column names are taken from the first query (before the UNION ALL). So this suffices:

```
select id, gpost, gtime from GROUPPOSTS
union all
select id, ppost, ptime from POSTS
order by gtime;
```

Of course one still can use an alias for the column. That's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: yes , I got it what I have to do , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to have only the order by statement in the last SQL section of the union all clause.
The entire combined resultset will be sorted by that column.

```
  select id, gpost, gtime as xtime from GROUPPOSTS
  union all
  select id, ppost, ptime as xtime from POSTS
  ORDER BY ptime
```